# How to make directory content browsable in an ASP.Net Core application through http pages?

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to show the directory content, so that users can browse it and click files to download them.

Is there a solution in ASP .Net Core to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest solution is to add a middleware with **app.UseDirectoryBrowser();**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseDirectoryBrowser();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
  app.UseCookiePolicy();

  app.UseMvc();
}
```

It gives the following result :

[image]

Moreover, a request path can be added so that it has to be included in the request.

```
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(requestPath:"/data");
```

i.e. : https://localhost:44386/data/

Last : file provider and file formatter can be provided :

```
  app.UseDirectoryBrowser(options:
    new DirectoryBrowserOptions(
      new SharedOptions()
      {
        // the IFileProvider class is a way to provide the files to be displayed
        FileProvider = new MyFileProvider()
      }
      )
    {
      // The IFileFormatter implementation is a way to customize presentation of the directory
      RequestPath = "/data2",
      Formatter = new MyFileFormatter()
    }
    );
```